# How to map a json to a data class that has a nested wrapper child?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I am trying to write a unit test for a GraphQL parser. I have this JSON file structure:

```
{
     "data": {
         "myVar": {
              "myArray": [{
                         "someVal": "someStr1",
                         "myVal": "myStr1", 
                   }, {
                         "someVal": "someStr2",
                         "myVal": "myStr2"
                   }
               ]
         }
     }
}
```

This is my MyDataClass.kt:

```
data class MyDataClass(
     myVar: MyBaseVar? = null
)

data class MyBaseVar(
    myArray: List<MyArrayListValue>? = null
)

data class MyArrayListValue(
     someVal: String? = null
     myPersonalData: MyPersonalData? = null
)

data class MyPersonalData( // The wrapper class around `myVal`
     myVal: String? = null
)
```

I was using

```
val jsonData = JsonParser.parseString(
     javaClass.getResourceAsStream(myJsonFile)!!.reader().readText()
).asJsonObject.get("data")

val myParsedData = Gson().fromJson(jsonData, MyDataClass::class.java)
```

However, since there is a slight difference between JSON structure and the data class, I'm unable to map `data.myVar.myArray[x].myVal` to `myParsedData.myVar.myArray[x].myPersonalData.myVal`. That is, `myParsedData.myVar.myArray[x].myPersonalData.myVal` is set to `null`.

Note that I don't want to change the JSON structure or the Data class structure as it is something that's provided to me. Instead, I want a way to correctly map the JSON to data class. Is there a better way to do it without having to manually walk down the tree and create a new instance of individual child nodes?

Comment: Why do you want to use a `data class` instead of just a `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom deserializer with Gson to handle the mapping logic for the nested properties. write a custom deserializer for `MyArrayListValue` to extract the `myVal` field from the JSON structure and set it to `myPersonalData.myVal`, you can follow the code bellow:

```
import com.google.gson.*
import java.lang.reflect.Type

data class MyDataClass(
    val myVar: MyBaseVar? = null
)

data class MyBaseVar(
    val myArray: List<MyArrayListValue>? = null
)

data class MyArrayListValue(
    val someVal: String? = null,
    val myPersonalData: MyPersonalData? = null
)

data class MyPersonalData(
    val myVal: String? = null
)

class MyArrayListValueDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<MyArrayListValue> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): MyArrayListValue {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject
        val someVal = jsonObject.get("someVal")?.asString
        val myVal = jsonObject.get("myVal")?.asString

        val myPersonalData = MyPersonalData(myVal)

        return MyArrayListValue(someVal, myPersonalData)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(MyArrayListValue::class.java, MyArrayListValueDeserializer())
        .create()

    val myJsonFile = "path/to/your/json/file.json"
    val jsonData = JsonParser.parseString(
        javaClass.getResourceAsStream(myJsonFile)!!.reader().readText()
    ).asJsonObject.get("data")

    val myParsedData = gson.fromJson(jsonData, MyDataClass::class.java)

    // Now myParsedData should have the correct mapping for myPersonalData.myVal
    println(myParsedData)
}
```

Above code, `MyArrayListValueDeserializer` class extends `JsonDeserializer<MyArrayListValue>` and overrides the `deserialize` method. Inside this method, it manually extracts the values from the JSON and constructs the `MyArrayListValue` object with the correct mapping for `myPersonalData.myVal`. The custom deserializer is then registered with Gson using `registerTypeAdapter` when creating the Gson instance.

***Hope it helps!***

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the snippet and explanation!